# How to tell python import modules automatically when use the -c option?

Tags: python

I write this command to test a regex very ofter:

```
$ python -c 'import re; print(re.sub("e", "E", "hello"))'
hEllo
```

The problem is that when I import multiply modules, command becomes longer and longer.
If I can config python to `import re; import XXX; import YYY;` automatically,
the command becomes much shorter:

```
$ python -c 'print(re.sub("e", "E", "hello"))'
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that. Can't you just write a shell script that prepends the imports to your argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of configuring Python it's much easier and more convenient to write a separate script to which you pass the regular expression to test:

```
test.py 're.sub("e", "E", "hello"))'
```

And `test.py` will import all needed modules (not tested):

```
import re
import XXX
import YYY
import sys

exec sys.argv[1]
```